# Click outside to turn off a button only when the button was clicked before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The button can change its color from plus(green) to minus(red) by clicking on it. I wish to click outside to change it to green only when button is red.

HTML

```
<button class="button13"></button>
```

CSS

```
.button13 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #70975B;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 1.1);
}

.button13:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.button13:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.button13.clicked {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  background: #CC2A41;
}

.button13.clicked:before {
  width: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(".button13").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");

});
```

So I add another function so that when I click outside, the button can also be clicked.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.button13')) {
        $('.button13').toggleClass("clicked");
    }
})
```

But it turns out that no matter the button is red or green, the button will be clicked.
I was thinking to create a variable and write a algorithm like:

```
int buttonstate = 0;
if(the button is clicked){
$(this).toggleClass("clicked");
buttonstate = 1;
}

if(click outside and buttonstate ==1){
$(this).toggleClass("clicked");
buttonstate = 0;
}
```

I am not sure if it can really work for my question and I am just using pseudo java to express my idea. Is that possible to realize this function in JS?

Here is my code:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Klaushu/ptjbgh27/2/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your button is clicked or not before toggle

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.button13')) {
             if( $('.button13').hasClass("clicked"))
                    $('.button13').toggleClass("clicked");
    }
})
```